# CSS file not found on MacOS

Tags: python, html, css, django, macos

I am a beginner at web development. I am using Python and Django on a Mac. When I want to link CSS to HTML, this shows in the command line and on the web page is still only text from the html file.

Command line:

```
Not Found: /style.css
[29/May/2021 17:37:12] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2095
```

This is my HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
    </head>

    <body>
       <p>Webpage</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my CSS file:

```
body {
background-color: royalblue;
}
```

Comment: can you please share directory structure?

Comment: Where is the css file located on disk?

Comment: What is the *question* here? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your static file is not matching any URL pattern rule. Configure [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) from here, and also configure `urls.py` [from here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) for development

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you do not have your CSS file in the same relative directory as the file you're working on.

If you have the CSS file in the root of your server directory, you may need to add `/` to the beginning of your path.

An example is if your directory structure looks like this

```
.
├── homepage.html
├── index.html
├── other
│   └── test.html <-- The page you are accessing
└── style.css
```

If in this page, you had `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`, it would not work, since `style.css` is not in the `other/` directory.

That is because, unless you specify, all the paths are **relative**.

You can specify that you **do not** want relative paths by adding `/` to the beginning of your path followed by the directory that `style.css` is located in.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
```

The `/` ensures that this will work in any file in the HTML directory